# Redirecting page after setingt Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my .htaccess I have:

set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';"

and have a good idea of what it means and does.  My problem is that I have multiple files that require a full re-direct.  As an example, my login screen.  My login page actually consists of 3 tabs, 1 for registering, 1 for login and another for forgot password.  Depending on the tab class button clicked, it triggers an external .js file.  That file evaluates what was clicked and then runs the individual files to filter and sanitize the data, checks the mysql and if all is good, re-directs to the user home page.

```js
cleandata.js:
// JOIN - This script will call up the file to check if fields are empty, etc.
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".sign_Tab1").click(function(event)
    {
        $.post("cleanjoin.php", $(".join_Form").serialize(),
            function(data)
            {
                $(".join_Mode").html(data);
            }
        );
    });
});
//
// SIGN - This script will call up the file to check if fields are empty, etc.
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".sign_Tab2").click(function(event)
    {
        $.post("cleansign.php", $(".sign_Form").serialize(),
            function(data)
            {
                $(".sign_Mode").html(data);
            }
        );
    });
});
//
// LOST - This script will call up the file to check if fields are empty, etc.
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".sign_Tab3").click(function(event)
    {
        $.post("cleanlost.php", $(".lost_Form").serialize(),
            function(data)
            {
                $(".lost_Mode").html(data);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

At the bottom of each "clean...." file, if good, redirect to the user home page with:

```html
<script>
    window.location.href='http://mysite/userHome.php';
</script>
```

I know why it is not re-directing, I just dont know how to get around it.  Any suggestion or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, are your `clean___.php` files in `http://mysite/`?

Comment: Hi, yes they are.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why you say the Content-Security-Policy is associated with this problem. The `<script>` tag you are returning will not get executed only by setting it inside the document using `.html(...)`

Comment: Yes, I know.  What is the work around for people using CSP and needing to do redirect to another page.  The header: in php doesnt work, inlining doesnt work, unless I allow them.  How do you get around it is my question.

Comment: @user3344341: Were you able to figure out the work around for this? I am facing a similar issue right now.